# Include parent directory in gulp src task

Tags: gulp

I would like to create a `resources.zip` file which will contain `css/styles.css`.
So far I have got most of this working, the only problem is the archive only contains the styles.css file and not its parent directory `css`.

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');

gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('css/*')
        .pipe(zip('resources.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Comment: could you try  `gulp.src('css/**/*.*')`?

Comment: Nope this returns the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to setup the base for the `gulp.src`:

`gulp.src('css/*', {base: '.'})`

This is because the default base is:

> Default: everything before a glob starts (see glob2base)

[source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase). Zipped file path: [zip](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip/blob/master/index.js#L66).